# Calculating the outer boundary of several Geometry objects in SQL Server 2008

Tags: polygon, sql-server

I have lots of `Polygons` of datatype `Geometry` in SQL Server 2008. The image below shows how a select of all these Geometrys looks visualized.

[image: Lots of Geometrys]

What I need to do is create a Polygon which represents the outer boundary of all these polygons. So I used the [response given to a previous spatial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154672/how-to-combine-multiple-linestring-rows-into-a-single-row-collection) I asked to create the following code:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(geom GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO @test SELECT geom FROM ForceBoundary

DECLARE @geom GEOMETRY
SELECT @geom = (SELECT TOP 1 geom FROM @test)
SELECT @geom = @geom.STUnion(geom) FROM @test

SELECT @geom
```

This produced the following result, which has *cracks* in it due to holes between the polygons:

[image: Combined polygons with cracks]

So I updated my query with the following change:

```
INSERT INTO @test SELECT geom.Reduce(0.001).STBuffer(100) FROM ForceBoundary
```

Which improved the result, however it's not solving the issue completely and it also damages the outer boundary accuracy.

[image: Combined polygons with less cracks]

**What is the correct way to achieve this?** From looking through a list of the STxxxx functions I couldn't see one that seemed to provide the results I need?

I've tried `SELECT @geom.STExteriorRing()` but it doesn't return anything. Appending it with `.STAsText()` returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to remove [slivers](https://en.mimi.hu/gis/sliver.html). There is a function for this in the [SQL Server Spatial Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20180126035817/http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com:80/) project - **FilterArtifactsGeometry**.

A blog post on using the function can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140429064958/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edkatibah/archive/2010/12/30/new-functions-added-to-the-sql-server-spatial-tools-codeplex-project.aspx) (via Archive.org) original removed from MSDN.

This has an option for filtering out small polygons using the **ringTolerance** parameter:

*Remove all polygon rings thinner than provided tolerance (e.g. ring.STArea < ringTolerance x ring.STLength). A value of 0 will not remove any rings.*

> In practice, this allows very thin polygon rings (slivers) to be
> detected and removed while leaving more typically shaped polygon rings
> alone.  The presumption is, of course, that slivers are undesirable
> but non-sliver rings are desirable.

Comment: It seems this SQL Server Spatial Tools library is very useful, I've used it several times now to plug holes in the basic SQL Server 2008 spatial functionality